# Prove a point has unique coordinates

Tags: vectors, solution-verification, analytic-geometry

Prove that a point $X$ determine it's coordinates uniquely.

My answer:
Let $X$ be a point in the plane with coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Suppose that X can also be determined by the coordinates $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$.

The distance between X and X is given by $\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+(x_3-y_3)^2} \neq 0$ since both sets of coordinates are not equal to zero, but this is a contradiction given that the distance between $X$ and $X$ should be zero since it's the same point.

Therefore $X$ is determined by one and only one set of coordinates.

Is this proof right?

Comment: The approach is fine

Comment: Thanks, but is the proof fine too?